# Implementation of jquery mmenu not visible in the view at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have implemented the jquery mmenu in my html but cannot see the navigation panel nor the hamburger icon on my view. I have also implemented angular js in the

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/jquery.mmenu.all.css">


<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
            $('nav#menu').mmenu({
                extensions  : [ 'effect-slide-menu', 'pageshadow' ],
                searchfield : true,
                counters    : true,
                navbar      : {
                    title       : 'Advanced menu'
                },
                navbars     : [
                    {
                        position    : 'top',
                        content     : [ 'searchfield' ]
                    }, {
                        position    : 'top',
                        content     : [
                            'prev',
                            'title',
                            'close'
                        ]
                    }, {
                        position    : 'bottom',
                        content     : [
                            '<a href="http://mmenu.frebsite.nl" target="_blank">Visit website</a>',
                            '<a href="http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/wordpress-plugin.html" target="_blank">WordPress plugin</a>'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
```

```
<nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">The team</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our address</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: I guess you have a script src for mmenu as well? Pure CSS menu is it?

Comment: Make sure that you have the appropriate JQuery Mmenu javascript file attached and make sure that you're using JQuery 1.7 or higher.  Also, place your JQuery file above your AngularJS file.

Comment: @jme11 I followed your instructions however I still cannot see the hamburger icon on the screen to click on and then view the navigation menu.

Comment: Have you added your page styles?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation of the **jQuery.mmenu plugin** it looks like you are missing the `.js` file in the `head` section, after the `jquery.min.js` request.

Make sure you add the file to the correct folder and add the following line to the `head` section of your file:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.mmenu.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

To show the menu trigger, you need to add it as it is not provided by the plugin.
To do so, simply add this to the `body` after the `</nav>` tag:

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="#menu"></a>
</div>
```

And add the CSS for the button either in the `head`section or in an external CSS file:

```
.header a{
   background: center center no-repeat #333;
   background-image: url( data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAAAZCAYAAADE6YVjAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAADhJREFUeNpi/P//PwOtARMDHQBdLGFBYtMq3BiHT3DRPU4YR4NrNAmPJuHRJDyahEeT8Ii3BCDAAF0WBj5Er5idAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC );
   display: block;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: adding the missed javascript also does not help the cause sadly :(

Comment: Like @jme11 said, make sure you are using JQuery 1.7 or higher when you call it.

Comment: I have implemented Jquery 1.7.2 however it still doesnt seem to show up.

Comment: You need to call the menu trigger externally as it's not provided by the plugin.

Comment: To add the menu trigger check the **Edit** in my answer.